# Enabling panel causes WinForms application to enter "Not Responding " mode

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, backgroundworker

I have an issue very similar to [DataGridView refresh causes "Not Responding" application (but only when not in Visual Studio)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/97905526-f6c3-4426-89b3-240bd71e4b62/datagridview-refresh-causes-not-responding-application-but-only-when-not-in-visual-studio?forum=csharpgeneral)

While loading my data to my Winforms app form, I temporary disable a panel filling the form and containing all the controls, and I enable it back when done.

As in the example, I work with `BackgroundWorker` to load data and use thread-safe `bgWorkerSend_ProgressChanged` or `bgWorkerSend_RunWorkerCompleted` to interact with the UI.

I also have a Windows Forms timer that refreshes in the same way the form after 5 minutes of idle time.

What is weird, is that at the end of the init load, the panel is enabled back correctly, while in the latter refresh, the application enters "Not Responding" mode, and remains there forever. Furthermore, this only happens when I execute directly the application. If executed from Visual Studio, it works correctly both at initial load and at refresh.

```
private void _bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ProgressPercentage == 100)
    {
        // re-enable panel
        panel1.Enabled = true;

        // the below is never reached !!?
        AnyInstruction();
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be a cross-threading issue, try enabling the panel on the UI thread instead.

Comment: My understanding is that the content of _bw_ProgressChanged is executed on the UI thread, isn't that correct ?

Comment: That only happens when you use the BGW correctly.  Strong hint that you don't.  Like calling the RunWorkerAsync() method from a worker thread instead of the UI thread.  Use the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window to verify.

Comment: I double checked and used the VS Debug > Windows > Thread with a breakpoint on RunWorkerAsync, and when it stopped there it showed it is from the main thread, both at init load, and at refresh time by timer. I assume Windows Forms timer_Tick() is executed from the main thread.

Comment: If it may help, actually `_bw.RunWorkerAsync()` is started from an event handler in the presenter class and not from the form class directly. The event is associated between the presenter and the form (view) with : `_view.DataLoaded += DataLoaded;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Narrowing down the issue, it showed that the problem was because the code inside `BackgroundWorker` thread was filling a `DataSet` that has been instantiated earlier in the main thread.

By moving the instantiation into the BackgroundWorker thread instead, resolved the issue, and `panel1.Enabled = true;` is now executed correctly in `_bw_ProgressChanged`.